# Why isn't my question block removed?

Tags: support

I have posted some questions in stackoverflow and I have got blocked for asking more questions. I have seen that my questions actualy was kind of bad, but I have fixed them. It still seems like stackoverflow doesn't notice it. I am thinking: Why?

I have fixed both of my posts: [JButton and JLabel dissappears when adding custom background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003052/jbutton-and-jlabel-dissappears-when-adding-custom-background)

[How can I create a file that stores user data in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005873/how-can-i-create-a-file-that-contains-user-data-in-java)

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions?

Comment: Even if improved, both questions are still heavily downvoted. Your "improvement" will need to be proven by a gain in reputation. Either on these questions or by any other contributions you can still make. The system is an automatic one. Your ban is not lifted by a person on a "well, I see he tried" basis. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers for more information.

Comment: In your second question, it appears that you have edited the question and added the solution to it. Instead, post your solution as an answer to your question. It *might* get you some rep.

Comment: @AshRj Unfortunately that question is closed and it will only be reopened if the question is improved. So the OP will be unable to post an answer until then.

Comment: Are you guys upwoting my questions?

Comment: I've got 20 reputation in only some minutes

Comment: @Bart Is it worth reopening now ? I dont see any other possible improvements possible without changing the question matter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005873/how-can-i-create-a-file-that-contains-user-data-in-java

Comment: closed as not a real question? In my opinion I would say that my question is a good question @AshRj Thanks for editing my post in a more organized way.

Comment: @joapet99 Everything that you are asking for can be easily found by searching. The question *would* have been good, had you attempted to solve the problem before posting and then describing your attempt and showing the code within the question.

Comment: @AshRj Could you give me an example? I have searched a bit on google, but maybe I haven't used the correct keywords.

Comment: Answer some questions, and delete very bad questions. Note that deleted questions still count for 30 days.

Comment: I'm scared for getting downvoted for bad answers.

Comment: @joapet99 How do you know that your answers are going to be bad? Just pick up a topic where you've got some knowledge, and answer these questions. Another way to gain reputation is by editing existing posts (of others).

Comment: How much reputation do I need before they are removing the block?